# Connecing to SnapChat API

Tags: php, python, objective-c, ios7, cryptography

We are currently developing an application that we would like to have a feature to post to snapchat.
My developer is having a hard time figuring it out.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

This was his most recent response

"I'm still working on the SnapChat API, but the thing is that the Secret Key that the Private Third Party API's have provided may have change by the SnapChat officially. Because the "auth_token" that I'm getting after applying the SHA256 Encryption Algo, is correct and same as that is shown in the hacked API's but reply coming is "Unauthorised User". Also the link (https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap) that you had provided is giving the same output.
So I think it seems quiet impossible to implement the SnapChat API."

Comment: I wonder how there is so many clients still around then.

Answer (score 3):

I would firstly like to state that it is against [Snapchat's Terms and Conditions](https://www.snapchat.com/terms/) to reverse engineer their application and to also use their API:

> You are hereby granted a limited, nonexclusive, non-sublicensable
>   license to access and use the Services and Snapchat Content. This
>   license is revocable at any time. This license is subject to these
>   Terms and does not include:
>
> - Accessing the Snapchat API with an
>     unauthorized or third-party client; and

To the contrary, I'd recommend that you read over the write up about the Snapchat API by [GibSec](http://gibsonsec.org/) if you are working on a third party application for Snapchat.

[Snapchat Full Disclosure](http://gibsonsec.org/snapchat/fulldisclosure/)

Comment: I often see answers on Stack Overflow endorsing an American corporation's attempt to bind the (international) reader into a contract they have not signed, and to date no-one has been able to offer a persuasive argument -- legal or otherwise -- that this ability exists. I imagine computer misuse laws would be tried by eager lawyers, but presumably (and hopefully) this would only apply if the API usage amounted to misuse.

Comment: I've [said elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31883633/472495) though that if the API is meant to be for Snapchat only, people can build on it if they wish, but they must be willing for their apps to break should the implementation change, or Snapchat implements an IP block.